# django - Dynamically add computed column to queryset

Tags: django

I have a database table containing 4 integer columns representing version information - Major, Minor, Cust, Rev.

I'd like to represent these as a single column in my form, with relevant padding. So:
0, 1, 2, 3 = [0.01.002.0003].

I realise that there are several ways to use SQL to do this, but I'm curious as to whether it's possible to do it on the django side? So, after:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
```

...can I then extend the queryset with an additional calculated field? Later I pass the Queryset to be serialized, and I need the calculated field present at this stage, so I don't think an attribute will work.

Answer (score 4):

`annotate` should help you:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate-args-kwargs

Comment: Hmmm - it looks like annotate is particularly concerned with aggregation. In this case, I'm not interested in adding an aggregated column - it's more of a re-formatting problem really. I can't find examples of annotate being used in this context.

While reading up on annotate, I did discover that annotate fields don't get serialized, so this probably means I back to doing the re-formatting on the SQL side anyways.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in SQL? Can't you just write some python or template code?

Comment: My template is using ExtJs and as such, I'm passing in JSON from the django serializer. This is generated directly from the querset, so I need to get the calculated field into the queryset somehow.

And, yes, I'm trying to find out if there is a way of doing that in Python.

Comment: Can you simply iterate over queryset and add generated fields? Won't they be serialized then?

Comment: For anyone interested, the way I solved this in the end was to write a custom JSON serializer.